# Can not remove creation date in Joomla template

Tags: javascript, joomla

Hello I would not like the article date to show at all, using a Joomla template. 
Have selected hide in both article settings and global settings, it still is there. I also went to template folder /html/com_content/article/default.php  and found files there and changed show to hide in all code, it is still there!!!

I changed code to:

```
$useDefList = (
$params->get('hide_modify_date') || 
$params->get('hide_publish_date')   || 
$params->get('show_hits') || 
$params->get('show_category') || 
$params->get('show_parent_category') ||
$params->get('show_author')
);
```

Still showing, what am I doing wrong? Please help Joomla junkies.

https://apsmc.org/  this is the webpage and date is showing up right above article in red.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not sure how else to ask?  I basically do not want dates to show on any articles in Joomla template.

Comment: I think it is probably a module not a regular article display.  Figure out what module that is and look for the settings there.    This isn't really a programming question and you might be better off at [joomla.se] the stackexchange site for Joomla.

Comment: Thank you Elin, I will try that forum.

Comment: I GOT IT!!! I did what you said with the module and found another level of options, thank you all of the help articles said to go to the index or global settings.  SO APPRECIATE!!!

Comment: @Amy if you have found a solution to your issue, please share your knowledge with others by posting an answer that explains what you did.  Then, of course, award your answer with the green tick.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove it from menu in items settings. All die/show (data, authors, icons) You can do there and inside articles.

Comment: This might be the right answer. In order to make it a good answer, you should add explanations and examples of how or why this is the correct solution. I advise reading the [answer] page for more info.

Comment: Hi Natalia, thank you for answering.  I did go to menu items home and used hide there, is that where you were talking about?  Thank you for your help, I am new to Joomla.

Comment: Yes. I was talking about it. Good luck!)

Comment: Give direct link with this date. I'll check it. And what's the Joomla Version?

Comment: https://apsmc.org/ scroll down and it is the date in red above "Idle Hands Program" it is version 3.4.8 I am afraid it will mess up theme if I update. I did do a backup so might give it a try? Thanks again for your help I am at a loss.

Comment: I got it Natalia but thanks so much for your help.  This is my first Joomla site so still getting the hang of.

Comment: I'm glad for You!) Good luck!